# Select group_concat with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the last date of the tour (RS_TO) for each product (RS_FC)
We consider that each product can be seen several times
The end goal is to have the product with its last surveillance

[Select group_concat with condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8xSI.jpg)

```
Select f.ID_PROD, f.IDENTIFIANT,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.DATE_TOURNEE 
ORDER BY t.DATE_TOURNEE ASC SEPARATOR ‘,’)
FROM RSF_FICHES_CANALISATION f
LEFT OUTER JOIN MR_RSF_PIPE_P_MR_RSF_SURVEY m ON m.ID_PROD=f.ID_PROD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RSF_TOURNEE t ON t.ID=m.ID_TOUR
GROUP BY f.ID_PROD
```

I tried this as a request but without success

Comment: I suspect  when you find yourself with a table called       MR_RSF_PIPE_P_MR_RSF_SURVEY, the battle is already lost. But see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT not needed for the final task solution. Use subquery and get greatest DATE_TOURNEE for each ID_PROD then get the whole row which matches this (ID_PROD, DATE_TOURNEE) pair. Or, if you have 8+ version, simply enumerate rows in CTE partitioning by ID_PROD and ordering by DATE_TOURNEE descending and return rows where the number is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not using the group by ?

```
Select f.ID_PROD, f.IDENTIFIANT,
MAX(t.DATE_TOURNEE)
FROM RSF_FICHES_CANALISATION f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MR_RSF_PIPE_P_MR_RSF_SURVEY m ON m.ID_PROD=f.ID_PROD
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RSF_TOURNEE t ON t.ID=m.ID_TOUR
GROUP BY f.ID_PROD, f.IDENTIFIANT
```

Comment: the solution works perfectly, imagine that I would have wanted to filter the largest values ​​in "MR_RSF_PIPE_P_MR_RSF_SURVEY"
how I should have done, I believe that it would have allowed me to increase the speed of my request

Answer (score 0):

To find the last date, you use `MAX()` aggregation on date, because a more recent date has an higher value